# Is the integral equal to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider
$$\int_{S_r} \left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\eta}\right)^2 (x\cdot\eta)\ d\sigma $$
Where $S_r$ is the sphere of radius $r$ and centered at zero, $\phi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\eta$ is the outward unit vector to the sphere. Can anyone explain what does this integral means? And is it true that the integral tends to zero as $r$ tends to infinity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its hard to make sense of it, are you sure you got the details right? The unit normal of a sphere at 0 is just $r$ times the coordinate vector, so why write it as $\eta$, and also you didn't assume any differentiability of $\phi$

Comment: So how would it he the expression of the integral? Abd $\phi$ is a $C^2\cap C_0$ On the ball of radius r